# I want to submit a form( without <form> tag ), when I press enter key on keyboard

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

```
<input type="text" name="username" id="username" placeholder="Username" />
<input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Password" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" onclick="validLogin()" class="submit" value="Login">
```

This is my form, when ever I fill password field and then hit on enter key on key form should submit.

**Edit:** Form submission code

```
function validLogin(){ 
  var uname=$('#username').val(); 
  var password=$('#password').val(); 
  var dataString = 'uname='+ uname + '&password='+ password; 

  $("#flash").show(); 
  $("#flash").fadeIn(400).html('<img src="image/loading.gif" />');
  $.ajax({ 
    type: "POST", 
    url: "login.php", 
    data: dataString, 
    cache: false, 
    success: function(result){
      var result = trim(result);
      $("#flash").hide();
      if(result=='correct'){
        window.location='al‌​l_departments.php';
      }else{
        $("#errorMessage").html(result);
      } 
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Why would you not use a `form` tag? that's what its for

Comment: You can't submit a form if it's not a form... think about that logic.

Comment: It is actually possible to "submit" a "form" without form-tags. what you need is an ajax-function, e.g. with jquery, which will get the values by id. But there is no reason not to use a form tho.

Comment: Actually I am posting data through Ajax so whenever I use form tag ajax not working

Comment: you should use form tag. Still you can send input data to server using $.ajax call using jquery.

Comment: post your ajax call code

Comment: function validLogin(){
      var uname=$('#username').val();
      var password=$('#password').val();
      var dataString = 'uname='+ uname + '&password='+ password;
      $("#flash").show(); $("#flash").fadeIn(400).html('<img src="image/loading.gif" />');
      $.ajax({ type: "POST", url: "login.php", data: dataString, cache: false,
      success: function(result){var result=trim(result);$("#flash").hide();if(result=='correct'){window.location='all_departments.php';}else{$("#errorMessage").html(result);}
      }});}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, you could try adding a `onkeyup` attribute to the password field and then checking which key it was that was pressed.

```
<input type="password" ... onkeyup="myFunction()" />
```

Alternatively, you could also try [jQuery's keyup bind](https://api.jquery.com/keyup/), which would look something like this:

```
$( "#password" ).keyup(function(evt) {
    if(evt.which == 13) { //If they press enter
        // Your AJAX code here
    }
});
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

That is not a form, those are just a couple of input tags. If you want to submit a form... you have to have a form in the first place.

If you want to avoid the normal submit of a form via AJAX, use `e.preventDefault()` or `return false;` in your submit handler for the form.

Comment: you can actually make ajax post-requests without forms, e.g. with jquery.ajax()

Comment: yes, but that's not the same as "submitting a form", right?

Comment: @TanuelMategi yes, you can. But the question was about posting forms and even when using ajax I would still use a form.

Comment: well its not exactly "submitting a form" but the user who clicks the "submit"-button doesnt know that. And yes, it is bad practice, so a form-tag should always be used.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible, but you shouldn't aim on that approach - and here are the reasons:

1) A form tag is required, due to the HTML standard.
2) Without the form tag, you won't be able to specify the method of your form (GET/POST) and the target.

That said - you may achieve submitting data, collected in your input tags, with pure JavaScript, however this is not valid HTML and some browser may not tolerate this - so don't do it...

Comment: I am Specifying the method using ajax Here is my ajax code:

function validLogin(){ var uname=$('#username').val(); var password=$('#password').val(); var dataString = 'uname='+ uname + '&password='+ password; $("#flash").show(); $("#flash").fadeIn(400).html('<img src="image/loading.gif" />'); $.ajax({ type: "POST", url: "login.php", data: dataString, cache: false, success: function(result){var result=trim(result);$("#flash").hide();if(result=='correct'){window.location='al‌​l_departments.php';}else{$("#errorMessage").html(result);} }});}